# Reorder matrix in R (corrplot)

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, r-corrplot

I have a 5x5 correlation matrix (much bigger but let's use this example) and am plotting the matrix using the `corrplot` package. While the package offers a few ways to reorder the columns and rows, I have found no manual way to do so.

How do I reorder a matrix that has column names 1:5 and row names 1:5 so that both change order to `k <- c(5,3,1,2,4)` instead of the current 1,2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: `mx[c(5,3,1,2,4), c(5,3,1,2,4)]`